# React-native and redux animation performance onPress

Tags: android, react-native, redux

I am rendering a ListView, each item is a `TouchableHighlight` with an `onPress` which dispatches an action to load data. The data is stored in state, which results in another section of the app to render underneath the list.

On Android, consecutive presses on list items causes the animation to delay until after the ajax requests have finished. Is there a way to make the highlight a priority so the the feedback isn't delayed?

```
//Handler
handleOnPress = () => {
    dispatch(makeAjaxRequest())
}

// Component
<TouchableHighlight onPress={this.handleOnPress}>
    <Text>List item</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `handleOnPress` function in this way, by rendering the page all the `onPress` events will call and it causes a lot of unwanted call of `handleOnPress` function if you modify the `onPress` prop to `onPress={this.handleOnPress}` this function will only call when you press an `TouchableHighlight` item and it will help you to reduce the delay and control the state properly. your code will be like this:

```
//Handler
handleOnPress = () => {
    dispatch(makeAjaxRequest())
}

// Component
<TouchableHighlight onPress={this.handleOnPress}>
    <Text>List item</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Comment: does it help you?

Comment: Oh sorry, that was just a typo when I wrote the example. Update :)

The handleOnPress only happens once per touchableHighlight. I have verified this